# RegEx Challenge: Capture all the numbers in a specific row

Tags: php, regex, text, notepad++, pcre

Assume we have this text:

```
...
settingsA=9, 4.2 
settingsB=3, 1.5, 9, 2, 4, 6
settingsC=8, 3, 2.5, 1
...
```

**The question is how can I capture all the numbers that are in specific row using a single step?**

Single step means:

- single regex pattern.
- single operation (no loops or splits, etc.)
- all matches are captured in one array.

Let's say I want to capture all the numbers that are present in row which starts with `settingsB=`. The final result should look like this:

```
3
1.5
9
2
4
6
```

---

**My failed attempts:**

```
<?php
    $subject =
        "settingsA=9, 4.2
         settingsB=3, 1.5, 9, 2, 4, 6
         settingsC=8, 3, 2.5, 1";

    $pattern = '([\d\.]+)(, )?' // FAILED!
    $pattern = '(?:settingsB=)(?:([\d\.]+)(?:, )?)' // FAILED!
    $pattern = '(?:settingsB=)(?:([\d\.]+)(?:, )?)+' // FAILED!
    $pattern = '(?<=^settingsB=|, )([\d+\.]+)' // FAILED!

    preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    if ($matches) {
        print_r($matches);
    }
?>
```

**UPDATE 1:** @Saleem's example uses multiple steps instead of a single step, unfortunately. I'm not saying that his example is bad (it actually works), but I want to know if there is another way to do it and how. Any ideas?

**UPDATE 2:** @bobble bubble provided a perfect solution for this challenge.

Comment: Please mention your environment, language. e.g. PHP, python, java, JavaScript etc. or even editor, Notepad++

Comment: I am guessing a generic engine, no language, other than Regex.

Comment: Yes, but this will be a multi-stage solution. capture + tokenizer

Comment: I have posted solution in python as php is not available at moment. However python and php regex are quite similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`\G` anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) to glue matches to the end of a previous match. This pattern which also uses [`\K` to reset](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) before the desired part would work with PCRE regex flavor.

```
(?:settingsB *=|\G(?!^) *,) *\K[\d.]+
```

- `(?:` opens a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group) for alternation
- match `settingsB`, followed by  `*` any amount of space, followed by literal `=`
- `|\G(?!^)` or continue where the previous match ended but not start
- `*,` and match a comma preceded by optional space
- `)` end of alternation (non-capturing group)
- `*\K` reset after optional space
- `[\d.]+` match one or more digits & periods.

If the sequence contains tabs or newlines, use [`\s`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for *whitespace character* instead of space.

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jA7oN4/1) or [PHP demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/531888)

[or this more compatible pattern](https://regex101.com/r/bU0bF9/2) with use of a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) instead of `\K` which should work in any regex flavor that supports the `\G` anchor (Java, .NET, Ruby...)

Comment: simply perfect! That's what I call regex magic. Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is python solution  but will post PHP rx later. However, python regex and php are quite similar.

```
(?<=settingsB=)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:, )?)+
```

> Python:

```
import re

subject = """
...
settingsA=9, 4.2
settingsB=3, 1.5, 9, 2, 4, 6
settingsC=8, 3, 2.5, 1
...
"""

rx = re.compile(r"(?<=settingsB=)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:, )?)+", re.IGNORECASE)
result = rx.search(subject)

if result:
    numString = result.group()

    for n in [f.strip() for f in numString.split(',')]:
        print(n)
```

> PHP

```
$subject =
    "settingsA=9, 4.2
     settingsB=3, 1.5, 9, 2, 4, 6
     settingsC=8, 3, 2.5, 1";

$pattern = '/(?<=settingsB=)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:, )?)+/i';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);

if ($matches) {

    $num = explode(",", $matches[0]);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($num); $i++) {
        print(trim($num[$i]) . "\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3
1.5
9
2
4
6
```

Comment: I pasted that into regex101.com and it only matches the last number - even when the regex is set to Python.  Any idea why?

Comment: @Saleem, thank you for replying, but there must be a better solution. I want to return the result in an array **without splitting**, eg. `(numString.split)`. Let regex do the splitting. Any ideas?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, it's because regex101 shows last group only. Please see https://regex101.com/r/wD4vQ5/1

Comment: @OlavH, yes I agree. There should be better solution but something is better than nothing in short time :)

Comment: Just for fun: you know `premature optimization is the root of all evil` One solution is apply two different regex. One to capture whole string as I did initially and than apply another regex on result of last capture to eliminate coma ` , `

Comment: Updated solution for PHP